# New lightbulb doesn't fit in fitting

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I had lightbulb in my bathroom that lasted for many years but finally blew. I took the blown lightbulb to the lighting store, and they gave me a replacement that they said would work.

However, I then found that the new bulb wouldn't fit into the light fitting. In short, the red line depicted below is shorter than the yellow line.

[image: The light fitting]

[image: The light bulb]

I'm confused about whether I should press hard on the copper-colored metal to push it apart (I think that's doable, though I'd have to push really quite hard) or whether maybe the lighting store were wrong and I have the wrong type of bulb.

As per the request in the comments I have taken a photo of the whole fitting, and have looked at the numbers underneath.

[image: Full fitting]

It says

PAT APPL 42845764
CAT No 60720 240V 60 W AC
SEC APPROVAL No CS 0799

Comment: Where are you located? A model number of the fixture would allow someone to look up the replacement lamp. And yes, you could bend the tabs to allow the bulb to attach and make contact. If you do this, turn off the fixture at the breaker first.

Comment: Australia. Do you know where I can find the model number of the fixture?

Comment: How much force did it take to remove the old bulb?  Also it appears the socket is very sensitive to left-right positioning, make sure your alignment is correct.

Comment: Model number should, if it hasn't worn off, be in the area that the lamp goes. If you can't find it, perhaps a full picture of the fixture.

Comment: The more I look at it, it looks like that lamp is not correct. It appears that there are no side tabs on the lamp base, just a single strip down the center, whereas the fixture is 2 side tabs. Do you still have the old lamp? Picture of that would help also.

Comment: Or, if you have another identical fixture in the house, you could compare the 2 lamps.

Comment: @JeffCates That's a really good point, but unfortunately the lighting store took away my old bulb, and there is no other bulb like this in my house. I will take another picture of the fixture instead.

Comment: @JeffCates Sorry for the slow reply, but finally I was able to take a fuller picture of the fitting and also to work out what the model numbers are.

Comment: For me this electrical contact is too wrecked to put it back to operation. Thinking about a new fixture could be a good idea.

Comment: Does the bulb have a plastic cap over the socket end? I looked all over the net and couldn't even find that bulb. It may be time to just replace the entire fixture with something newer.

Comment: It doesn't have a plastic cap on the socket end. Thanks for your advice - I am going to follow your advice and just remove the entire fixture. Thank you! If you want to write up advice to remove the fixture as an answer I will accept it, or otherwise I will answer my own question. Having talked to people IRL I'm convinced that getting rid of the fixture is the right solution.